# Automated functional UI testing with GTK+2

Tags: c, user-interface, automated-tests, gtk

I'm following [this tutorial](https://opensource.com/article/17/7/functional-testing) on how to write a functional test for GUI built from GTK+2 in C. From the tutorial, it seems that the test cases are actually running as a part of the main GUI program. Is there anyway that we could run the test cases as a separate program using just the provided [testing module](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Testing.html#gtk-test-spin-button-click) provided by GTK?

EDIT: What I am trying to achieve here is to be able to test the functionality of the GUI program without modifying the original program as I am not allowed to. Is this goal really feasible with the testing module provided by GTK? I figured something like dogtail would have been better suited for the job but the system that I am working on is so old that getting dogtail up and running for it would be a difficult tasks.

Comment: GTK objects can only be accessed in the main thread that started GTK. What would it mean for them to run "as a separate program"? Do you want to have one program with the normal GUI and another that pokes into it and tests stuff on its widgets? That won't work for the given reason. If you can explain what you are trying to do, rather than just how you are currently thinking of doing it, you are probably more likely to get answers.

Comment: Anyway, since GTK 2 is now end-of-life, I wouldn't recommend writing any new code against it, and any existing code should be planned to migrate to at least GTK3, ideally the new 4. (I'm not sure whether they provide this kind of testing code, although I might guess no, and I suspect functional testing is better left to users than to event-poking...)

Comment: @underscore_d Basically, I am trying to write a test program for a GUI program using GTK+2 without modifying the original GUI program as I am not allowed to. The reason that I am working with GTK+2 is because this is the GUI for a really old embedded system which would not be able to run GTK3, so I only left with a few options to work with.